# Inserting table values from list iteration in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I try to iterate from result list and try to insert values in the table exdata but i look every where for the solution but nothing is working for me

```
if not result:
    print 'list is empty'
else:
    for i in xrange(0,len(result)):
        for item  in  result[i].iteritems():
            query="INSERT INTO exdata (cve_id,severity, published,modified) \
                   VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (item[i], item[1][0],item[1][1],item[1][2])
        cursor.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues in your code:

1) need to execute query in loop
2) Add commit statement for fixing changes

```
if not result:
    print 'list is empty'
else:
    for i in xrange(0,len(result)):
        for item  in  result[i].iteritems():
            query="INSERT INTO exdata (cve_id,severity, published,modified) \
                   VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (item[i], item[1][0],item[1][1],item[1][2])
            cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
```

Comment: it should be db.commit not a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `commit` to actually insert the values to the DB.
Also note that your `execute` is outside the inner loop, so it will execute only the query of the last iteration.

```
if not result:
    print 'list is empty'
else:
    for i in xrange(0,len(result)):
        for item  in  result[i].iteritems():
            query="INSERT INTO exdata (cve_id,severity, published,modified) \
                   VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (item[i], item[1][0],item[1][1],item[1][2])
            cursor.execute(query)

            cursor.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use  MySQLdb and want to do a multi-row insert,
try to use `executemany`:

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("myhost", "myuser", "mysecret", "mydb")
# users is a list of (userid, first_name, last_name, company)
c = db.cursor()
c.executemany("""INSERT INTO users
(userid, first_name, last_name, company)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", users)
db.commit()
db.close()
```

In MySQLdb, this is converted internally to a multi-row INSERT, which is reported to be 2-3 orders of
magnitude faster.